# JWT - Find private key by using the KID in key-store in Java

Tags: java, jwt

Good day. Is there a call in a Java that can use a KID from a JWT header that will find the correct private key in the key-store? I know how to do it, using the alias, but do not see anything using the KID. Thank you.

Comment: There are no KIDs in a Java keystore, only aliases. You will have to arrange matters so that they are the same thing. But how is the peer going to know your private KID?

Comment: Why do you want the _private_ key? You should verify a JWT using the issuer's public key, which you should be able to find at `ISSUER_URL/.well-known/jwks.json`. And, of course, you need to have the `ISSUER_URL` configured in your application; don't use the `iss` claim in the JWT!

Comment: I am the issuer, the client will send me a message. I then need to use that KID to see which private cert I must use to decrypt the message. There will be multiple private certs in my key-store. So I use the private key with - RSADecryptor(privateKey)

Comment: This is not my implementation, it is a big international company that use the KID to find the key dynamically between other keys.

Comment: Just to clarify, the KID in the key-store is part of a few bytes in the private key. Seems I will have to read every private key and compare those bytes at a certain position with the KID then. Will cache it for the day not to go through the process every time.